# workmail with django rest framework not work

Tags: django-rest-framework, smtp, smtplib, amazon-workmail

I am try to connect my workmail to django for sending mail but it not work. Below is my django setting for my workmail.

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mail.us-east-1.awsapps.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465 
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

For `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` is just for example. but `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` I use the password for login to workmail, so I don't know it correct or not.

And here is the code for sending mail

```py
from django.core.mail import send_mail
...
send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False)
```

Please help me to give answer or there is anything for me to try.

expect to give any suggestion and debugging